# Titanium - reload tableview data?

Tags: iphone, android, titanium

So I have a Titanium.UI.tableview in my main window in my tab group which displays a list of questions.

In another tab I have an "add a question" form. When this is filled out and submitted if it all goes through I need to be able to update the data in the table view in the first window.

How would I do this? I don't mind where it happens... I was trying to find a way of refreshing the tableview data when you click onto that tab, but if there's some way of "remotely" updating the table view (from the add a question view) that would be the best way really (so it doesn't have to update EVERY time you click that tab).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about this, but maybe you can try to store your questions as a list property for the app??

```
Ti.App.Properties.setList('Questions',YOURLIST);
```

Then when you're filling out the TableView rows just call each question in a loop

```
for(var i = 0 ;i< Ti.App.Properties.getList('Questions').length;i++)
{ use Questions[i] to fill up row }
....add to TableView
```

That way, whenever you need to add a new question to the list, just call it and push your new question into the list.

```
var tempList = Ti.App.Properties.getList('Questions');
tempList.push(NEWQUESTION);
Ti.App.Properties.setList('Questions',tempList);
```

Comment: hmm, that's actually a really good idea. That way it won't have to query the database every time you add a new question.

Comment: Then what? Would I use `window.addEventListener('focus'...` to refresh the tableview?

Comment: Maybe I got your question wrong, but if your TableView is in another (tab or) window,every time you click the tab, your window is redrawn...so maybe you can try to put the for loop in that window (one with the table)?? The list is an app property so it will persist beyond an app session...everytime you the window is drawn, it will take its questions from the list 'Questions'.

Comment: oh wait...do you want the updated table to be shown immediately after a new question is added??? In that case perhaps you should add a 'submit' button and in its 'click' listener, add the new question to the list and then just open the window with the TableView in it.

Comment: hmm, not sure what you mean. If I put `alert('hello')` at the top of the js file for the window the first time the window is show the alert shows. Then clicking to a new tab and back to the first one again the alert ISN'T shown. (iPhone at least). Similarly the question list doesn't update.

Comment: just this doesn't work: `var win = Titanium.UI.currentWindow; alert('hello');` It works the first time, but then it doesn't refresh the view when you revisit it.

Comment: So that means the window is not being redrawn after all!I guess that leaves us with only the "window.addEventListener('focus'.." option...did you try that??But then you'll have to remove the tableview and add it to the window again when the window gains focus...

Comment: nah, I've put `tableview.data = dataArray` into a function and just called THAT function on window focus. :)

Answer (score -2):

```
[tableView reloadData] ;
```

this method will refresh your UITableView with changed DataSource.You can add this in you
viewWillAppear method